# Sketch.js - the brush starts below the mouse pointer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Working :
http://jsfiddle.net/3rxvnrLp/1/

New:
http://jsfiddle.net/g3sTL/229/

Check out the working fiddle. If you hold the left click and start dragging the mouse, the brush marking starts at the tip of the mouse pointer.

But in the 'New' fiddle that i tried, the brush marking starts somewhere below the tip of the pointer.

How to fix this.

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <div id="content">
        <img src="http://www.lynnecalder.com/house_clipart.gif">                 
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var body = $('body');
    body.css({
        'position': 'relative',
        'top': '70px'
   }).append('<div id="MarkerTools"></div><canvas id="simple_sketch"></canvas>');
    $('#simple_sketch').sketch();
})
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#MarkerTools {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background: #2b539a;
}
#simple_sketch {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    border:1px solid green;
}
```

Comment: Your new one does not work ;) you forgot the js

Comment: Sorry, wrong url. Updated. Please check now.

Comment: The first has the same problem but then the brush draws above the cursor instead of under it.

Comment: @VincentBeltman. If you press & hold for a sec. The dot is just a few em away from the pointer which is fine, unlike the new one where the distance is noticable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has something to do with canvas and the height/width style. You're better of using the attributes for this. Change your js to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var body = $('body'), height = 200, width = 200; # You can calculate height and width here. DONT USE % or em for a canvas!!!.
    body.css({
        'position': 'relative',
        'top': '70px'
    }).append('<div id="MarkerTools"></div><canvas id="simple_sketch" height=' + height + ' width=' + width + '></canvas>');
    $('#simple_sketch').sketch();
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g3sTL/230/